# Is it reasonable to block a tag from being used given that an entire site exists for the topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

I am wondering if it is reasonable to block the [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) tag from being added to new questions on Stack Overflow, given these circumstances:

- A dedicated Stack Exchange site exists: [**Mathematica**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).
- The vast majority of all *Mathematica* users on Stack Exchange, and virtually all experts, have moved to the new site; only a few skilled users still answer *Mathematica* questions on Stack Overflow
- Many of the new questions tagged [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) have nothing to do with *Mathematica*; it is mistakenly used in place of (or usually in addition to) [math](/questions/tagged/math).
- Many of the remaining uses of [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) are merely referential, saying something like "Mathematica has function X that does Y; how can I implement this in Python?" See these questions from yesterday which I have not yet retagged: [Cartoonish style plots in MATLAB or Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21579320/618728) and [numpy array split/partition efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580693/numpy-array-split-partition-efficiency)

Given these facts would it not be better to keep this tag from being used in the future?  New questions belong on [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com), and if users could be directed there I think it would be better for all involved.

I continue to review the [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) tag on Stack Overflow, but I'm getting tired of untagging half of the questions for misapplication, and directing the authors of the other half to the correct site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that's not a reason to blacklist a tag. There is an *overlap* of subjects, [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) questions are not necessarily off-topic.

Blacklisting is to be reserved for tags that have *no place whatsoever* on a site, but that keep coming back to life. [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) is no such hard-to-kill zombie.

Quoting from the [blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/blacklist-request) tag wiki:

> Tags must be "quite bad" to be blacklisted. Generally, these are tags that could never convey any useful information or are actively harmful to the site. Because of the potential consequences of getting something wrong, only the dev team is able to add tags to a site's blacklist.

Instead, update the tag wiki to point out that the new site exists. Subscribe to the tag and educate users. Remove it where necessary. In other words: let the community police this. If you are tired of doing this, then let someone else fill the breach for a while, you don't *have* to do this either.

Comment: Is there really a place for this tag on Stack Overflow?  What is it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I don't mind a question asking 'how do I do this Mathematica thing in [Language X]' using the tag, for example. A mathematica expert with Language X knowledge may well be able to help.

Comment: That's not usually how it works though.  IMO the feature must be articulated in enough detail for non-*Mathematica*-users to understand.  The only remaining case is "translate this code from Mathematica to MATLAB for me kthxbye" which I don't think anyone appreciates.  (A user is welcome to post a code section on [Mathematica.SE] and ask for an explanation of how it works.)

Comment: Regarding: the last paragraph in your answer, the tag wiki already points out the new site but many people miss that.  I know I don't *have* to do this, but there are a number of users who were glad that I bothered to point out the new site (and often answer their questions while I do so).  I really feel like I need a big sign that says: **DO NOT ENTER -- WRONG WAY**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Even *if* the tag should no longer be used *in your opinion*, that doesn't make the tag a candidate for blacklisting. Mathematica questions once did *not* have a place of their own, and questions about it would **still** be on-topic!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sure, there is a better place now, but that doesn't make questions off-topic or a tag strictly off-limits.

Comment: Okay.  Do you have a suggestion for how this might be improved, besides just ignoring the problem or continuing doing what I'm doing now?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: continue what you are doing now; there will always be users that don't read the instructions in front of them, I am afraid. Blacklisting the tag is **not** the solution here.